# Filter Google Analytics Data by a specified page ID

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to put some HTML or JavaScript on my pages to give each page a unique ID that I can then use to filter my Google Analytics data?

**One example of a benefit:**
Right now, I'm filtering by a page's URL which contains a slug.  The slug, however, can change, so it would be much more accurate to be able to set some kind of ID on the page and reference that when filtering the data.

There are many other benefits to being able to do this, but that's one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it passing data (page ID) in a custom dimension as hit scope, then you can find it in the reports.